# How to calculate max_connections for PostgreSQL and default_pool_size for pgbouncer?

Tags: linux, database, postgresql, database-administration

Is there a rule or something I can use to calculate a good number for `max_connections`, `default_pool_size` and `max_client_conn`?

The defaults are odd. PostgreSQL defaults to max_connections=100 while pgboucner defaults to default_pool_size=20. Shouldn't default_pool_size always be higher than max_connections? Otherwise, what's the point? I thought pgbouncer was meant to let us handle more connections by lowering their overhead (by reusing PostgreSQL's connections). I'm confused.

I'm looking for advice similar to the ones found in [PostgreSQL's wiki](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Tuning_Your_PostgreSQL_Server), like "this parameter should be ~50% of your memory".

I also remember there was a spreadsheet for MySQL that would let you calculate these kind of parameters. It would be awesome to have something like that for PostgreSQL/pgbouncer.

Answer (score 0):

default_pool_size should always be less than max_client_conn. max_client_connection is the number of socket connections between the application and pgbuffer. default_pool_size is the number of connections between pgbuffer and the db.

So if you are using transaction as your pool mode you can share the smaller default_pool_size with the larger number of clients.